# Any way to expand Scala import automatically in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 in our scala project.
Our project code style defined that import statements should not collapse into one line.

For example,

prefered:

```
import com.example.domain.A
import com.example.domain.B
import com.example.domain.C
```

not prefered:

```
import com.example.domain.{A, B, C}
```

However, I could not find any options to make codes be prefered style when optimize import.
Are there an option? or should I use some plug-in?

Comment: Good question, because [java and groovy **has** this option](http://take.ms/0KDNx). However, relevant section is missing in scala code style group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the newest version of IntellJ IDEA(13.1.3) and Scala plugin(0.38.437) supports multi-line import.

Install and uncheck the option `Preferences` -> `Code Style` -> `Scala` -> `Imports` -> `Collect Imports with the same prefix into one import`

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that your project code style guide doesn't quite align with Scala. "import com.example.domain.{A, B, C}" would achieve the same thing you are trying but in a concise manner. Some would argue that this is the preferred way.

Maybe you should question your project code style?

Comment: I agree with your opinion, because the style is very ugly for Scala code.
Howerver merge conflict occurs very frequently in case using {}
import. So we decided not to use {}. Or any solutions?